# Can't load an image in laravel-mpdf with artisan serve

Tags: laravel-8, mpdf

I am trying to load logo image in the pdf file using [Laravel Mpdf](https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf) in Laravel 8. Below is some code which I am using in img tag.

```
<img style="height: auto; width: 150px;" src="/storage/images/{{ $company_details->company_logo }}" />
```

The below error comes after a minute for timeout.

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

Without image tag everything is working fine. Pdf file is loading in 2 to 3 secs.

Please let me know if i am missing anything here for loading image file using Laravel Mpdf. Thank you.

Okay I am adding files to it for more clear view of problem.

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\PdfController;

Route::get('/invoices/pdf', [PdfController::class,'generate_pdf']);
```

**PdfController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\CompanyDetails;
use PDF;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    
    public function generate_pdf()
    {   
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoices.pdf', [
            'company_details' => CompanyDetails::orderBy('company_id', 'asc')->first()
            
        ], [
            'title' => 'PDF Title',
            'author' => 'PDF Author',
            'margin_left' => 20,
            'margin_right' => 20,
            'margin_top' => 40,
            'margin_bottom' => 20,
            'margin_header' => 10,
            'margin_footer' => 10,
            'showImageErrors' => true
        ]);

        return $pdf->stream('pdf-file.pdf');
    }
}
```

Only problem with it is without image its working fine but with image there is timeout error.

Comment: Share details about the image, format, file size...

Comment: Image format is PNG and size is 18KB

Comment: That's still not enough information, isn't it? Unless you provide all the information to reproduce your use case, noone can help you. Share your code, share the image, share details about your stack, see MCVE https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean

Comment: @Finwe added files to it now. please check.

Comment: Good. And the image? There must be something off with the image itself.

Comment: I have tried with different PNG and JPG images both didn't work. You can try with any image from web.

Comment: For example take this PNG image link for reference

https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6702291_preview.png

Comment: Are you by any chance using artisan serve for running the application?

Comment: Yes its in development mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by changing below line

```
<img style="height: auto; width: 150px;" src="/storage/images/{{ $company_details->company_logo }}" />
```

to

```
<img style="height: auto; width: 150px;" src="storage/images/{{ $company_details->company_logo }}" />
```

the slash(/) was the problem. I think it was considering it as a HTTP resource.

Answer (score 1):

mPDF can not properly load external resources with single threaded servers.

As mentioned in documentation and in readme,

> mPDF has some problems with fetching external HTTP resources with single threaded servers such as php -S. A proper server such as nginx (php-fpm) or Apache is recommended.

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf#known-server-caveats

Comment: I am using Xampp Apache localhost server, why isn't it working for an image which is from project's storage folder ?

Comment: Define "isn't working". Path beginning with / by default means absolute HTTP path to current domain. You'd need to use file:// scheme or set a local basepath for the mPDF instance. But this is off topic in the scope of this SO Question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use php artisan just open another server with other port, example:

```
php artisan serve
```

this is your main server: http://localhost:8000

open another command shell, terminal etc... and create another server, help you serve images to mpdf:

```
php artisan serve --port 8081
```

this will create another server, http://localhost:8081, you can use another port by change `--port` arg.

So inside your mpdf you can use something like that:

```
$document->WriteHTML('<img src="http://localhost:8081/storage/logo.jpg" />');
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but i fix all images from absolute bath to relative path

e.g in my case i change

```
src="{{assets('assets/logo.jpg')}}"
```

to

```
src="assets/logo.jpg"
```

The assets function generates something like http://youripordomain